# SQL Aggregation with only one table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So this problem has been bugging me a little for the last week or so. I'm working with a database which hasn't exactly been designed in a way that I like and I'm having to do a lot of work-arounds to get the queries to function in a way I would like.

Essentially, I'm trying to remove duplicate entries that occur as a result of an instance caused by a previous entry. For the sake of argument say that a customer places an order or issues a job (this only occurs once) but as a result of the interactions a series of other rows are created to represent, sub-orders or jobs. Essentially, all duplicate records should have the same finish time so what I'm trying to create is a query which will return the record which has the earliest start time and ignore all other records which have the same finish time. All this occurs within the same table.

Something like:

```
select starttime
,      endtime
,      description
,      entrynumber
from   table 
where  starttime = min 
and    endtime   = endtime
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably what you want is something like this:

```
;WITH OrderedTable AS
(
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY endtime ORDER BY starttime) as rn, starttime, endtime, description, entrynumber
From Table
)

Select starttime, endtime, description, entrynumber
FROM OrderedTable
WHERE rn=1
```

What this does is group all the rows with the same end time, ordered by start time and give them an additional "row number" column starting at 1 and increasing. If you filter by rn = 1, you get only the earliest start time rows, ignoring the rest.